# Jquery to slide next and prev owl carausel

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, frontend, owl-carousel

I'm willing to slide owl carousel with the help of Jquery. Here is my code kindly help me correcting it.

```
    $('#slide-next').click(function() {
        $('#slider').trigger('owl.next');
    });
    $('#slide-prev').click(function() {
       $('#slider').trigger('owl.prev');
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery next and prev button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018638/jquery-next-and-prev-button)

Answer (score 0):

The correct events are: [next.owl.carousel and prev.owl.carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).

```js
$("#slider").owlCarousel();
$('#slide-next').click(function() {
    $('#slider').trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
$('#slide-prev').click(function() {
    $('#slider').trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  
<button id="slide-next">Next</button>
<button id="slide-prev">Prev</button>
<div id="slider" class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content1 </div>
  <div> Your Content2 </div>
  <div> Your Content3 </div>
  <div> Your Content4 </div>
  <div> Your Content5 </div>
  <div> Your Content6 </div>
  <div> Your Content7 </div>
</div>
```